# Google Test: "char-array initialized from wide string"

Tags: c++, googletest

I have implemented type-parameterized tests ([Sample #6](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/source/browse/trunk/samples/sample6_unittest.cc)) to apply the same test case to more than one class. It happens that when assigning a string to either a `signed char[]`, `unsigned char[]`, `const signed char[]` or `const unsigned char[]`, I get:

```
../stackoverflow.cpp: In member function ‘void IosTest_DummyTest_Test<gtest_TypeParam_>::TestBody() [with gtest_TypeParam_ = std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >]’:                           
../stackoverflow.cpp:34:   instantiated from here
../stackoverflow.cpp:32: error: char-array initialized from wide string
```

What is more interesting is that when applying the test case to one type everything goes just fine, but when I add a second type it blows up. I could reproduce the error in the following code:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <iostream>

// Factory methods
template<class T> std::ios* CreateStream();

template<>
std::ios* CreateStream<std::istream>() {
  return &std::cin;
}

template<>
std::ios* CreateStream<std::ostream>() {
  return &std::cout;
}

// Fixture class
template<class T>
class IosTest: public ::testing::Test {
 protected:
  IosTest() : ios_(CreateStream<T>()) {}
  virtual ~IosTest() {}
  std::ios* const ios_;
};

using testing::Types;
typedef Types<std::istream, std::ostream> Implementations;
TYPED_TEST_CASE(IosTest, Implementations);

TYPED_TEST(IosTest, DummyTest) {
  signed char c[] = ".";
  this->ios_->fill(c[0]);
};
```

In the line `typedef Types<std::istream, std::ostream> Implementations;` is created a list of types called `Implementations` and in the following line, `TYPED_TEST_CASE(IosTest, Implementations);`, is defined that the test case `IosTest` will be applied to the typed defined in the `Implementations` list.

As I have already said, if I remove either `std::istream` or `std::ostream` from the `Implementations` list I can compile and run the tests without any warning (I am using the `-Wall` flag). Can anyone explain this phenomenon?

Comment: I can't see the code on the google test site since I am forced to use an ancient browser at work, but it seems to me that when you include only one, it for some reason uses char strings, but when you include both, it is using wchar_t strings. I'd look into how the template is being expanded for clues.

Comment: Line 32 is `signed char c[] = ".";` ? That's the only `char[]` I see.

Answer (score 0):

Is it is possible your gtest library was built with a different version compiler that you are compiling your app (stackoverflow.cpp) with? I recall seeing this error message related to a lib I had built with a newer version of gcc and trying to link it with an older version of gcc.

You can try building gtest from source. It comes with a script that extracts and fuses everything into a single header file and a single cpp file.

Look in your gtest installation for this python script:

```
gtest/scripts/fuse_gtest_files.py
```

There are instructions in the script for how to run it. You end up with two files:

- gtest-all.cc
- gtest.h

You only need to do this once and add it to your makefile. I do exactly this for distributing a Linux-based app to a customer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like GCC bug described [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20140).

If you change `signed char c[] = ".";` to `char c[] = ".";` everything seems to work just fine.